# Finding $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for $x=t^3-12t$ and $y=t^2-1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

This is my attempt at finding $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. Can some one point out where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: I'm very confused. Which is correct? The paper or the title for $x$?

Comment: You could also learn some mathjax-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your title which disagrees with the working on your paper...

$$x=t^2-12t$$
$$y=t^2-1$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2t-12$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2t$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{2t}{2t-12}=\frac{t}{t-6}$$

But if the title is a typo then:

$$x=t^3-12t$$
$$y=t^2-1$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=3t^2-12$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2t$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{2t}{3t^2-12}$$

The following step is where you go wrong. Here's what you should've done - you need to differentiate with respect to $x$, not $t$:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}=\frac{d\left(\frac{2t}{3t^2-12}\right)}{dx}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d\left(\frac{2t}{3t^2-12}\right)}{dx}\times\frac{dt}{dt}=\frac{d\left(\frac{2t}{3t^2-12}\right)}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}$$

As seen in the above line, you're a $\frac{dt}{dx}$ out thanks to that mistake.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{2(3t^2-12)-2t(6t)}{(3t^2-12)^2}\times\frac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{(6t^2-24)-12t^2}{(3t^2-12)^3}=\frac{-6t^2-24}{(3t^2-12)^3}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-2}{9}\left(\frac{t^2+4}{(t^2-4)^3}\right)$$

In addition to the above mistake mentioned, you've randomly missed a squared in the penultimate line in the denominator of the fraction.

Comment: Yea. Title was a typo. Think I get it now. So it's pretty much just the derivative of dy/dx times one over dx?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "times". $d\over dx$ is more of an operator. Although this is just my personal preference.

Comment: As an aside, when someone uses $\frac d{dx}$ like a fraction, it can usually be justified through the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: You seem to be very active, and so I'd like to invite you to [my chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54911/simply-beautiful-arts-realm-of-calculus-and-analysis), where you may feel free to hang around as you please.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong because you have not computed 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} 
$$
but

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{dy}{dx} 
$$

if you set 
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\dot y \qquad \frac{dx}{dt}=\dot x
$$
than the formula for the second derivative is:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dt} \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{\dot x \ddot y-\dot y \ddot x}{\dot x^3}
$$
For a proof you can see :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_derivative#Second_derivative

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it this way:

Find $\large\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\large\frac{dy}{dt}$. Note that $\large\frac{dt}{dx}= \frac{1}{\large\frac{dx}{dt}}$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$

And then differentiate again to find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 3t^2 - 12$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= 2t$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2t}{3t^2-12} $$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{(3t^2-12)(2)-2t(6t)}{(3t^2-12)^2} \times \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{(3t^2-12)(2)-2t(6t)}{(3t^2-12)^2}  \times \frac{1}{3t^2-12}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{-2(t^2 + 4)}{9(t^2-4)^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Update...
I see 2 different mistakes.  One in the middle and one at the end.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac {2t}{3t^2-12}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx})\frac{dx}{dt}$.  Looks like you left out the $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Toward the end, you dropped the exponent.

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac{(3t^2 - 12)(2) - 2t(6t)}{(3t^2-12)^3}$

$\frac{-6t^2-24}{(3t^2-12)^3}$

Comment: I can't see that first mistake you mention at the beginning. Where?

Comment: does x = t^2 - 12x or x = t^3 - 12x... your headline doesn't match your paper... I will edit my response using  x = t^3-12x

Comment: The question is not mine :)

Comment: I was thrown by your handle and took it literally.